# Automatic control - linearization with two states

Tags: control, linear, state-space

I don't understand a part of the solution to c) of this problem, namely linearization at a stationary point using Taylor series and partial derivatives.

I am used to linearization of \$ f(x,u) \$ (two variables) using Taylor series but not \$ f(x_1,x_2,u) \$ (three variables) at a stationary point.

Taylor for two variables is given by (where second row is ignored):
[image: taylor]

Are we supposed to linearize using Taylor series for three variables or just find the partial derivative of \$f_1\$ and \$ f_2 \$? We get a term \$ f(x^0_1,x^0_2,u^0) \$ (which looks like \$ f(a,b) \$ from Taylor series formula for two variables above) [present](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=41HYQG8BjPA) in the solution which is set to zero that is not present if we were to just find the partial derivative of \$f \$ with respect to all terms and just sum them up?

*Sorry if the question is a bit messy since I have trouble connecting the mathematical theory with the control theory.*

---

[image: Problem]

### **Solution:**

[image: Solution part 1]

[image: solution part 2 here]

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are aware of the concept of the Jacobian matrix. This is a case of *Linearization of Multistate Models*. See, for example, pages 6-7 of 
[Linearization of Nonlinear Models](https://myweb.ntut.edu.tw/~jcjeng/Linearization.pdf).

Yes, that linearization uses the calculation of the partial derivatives of  three functions with **three variables** (two states \$x_1\$, \$x_2\$ at one input \$u\$) around the equilibrium point \$Q\$. The definition of the Taylor series expansion (neglecting the h.o.t. - high-order terms) already suggests the use of the deviation variables:
$$\Delta x_1 = x_1-x_{1_Q}$$
$$\Delta x_2 = x_2-x_{2_Q}$$
$$\Delta u = u - u_Q$$

with which the final linearized model is built. Also, note that, for example:
\$\dot{\Delta x}=\dot{x_1}\$, since \$\dot{x_{1_Q}}=0\$.